# How to make Google App script triggers to run on script executions or API requests?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am aware that installable triggers [do not execute/run on Script executions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) or updates via API requests. For triggers to run, the change or edit has to be done 'manually'. Is there any work-around or solution to this?

**Here is my usecase:**

- I have designed HTML UI that accepts some data and stores that in specific spreadsheet
- Since I didn't want any users to have access to backend spreadsheet (to restrict view to other's submission), I have created REST service using [TIBCO Cloud Integration > Google connector](https://community.tibco.com/questions/using-flogo-connector-google-sheets) that writes data to Google spreadsheet
- When user submit the response, UI internally invokes above-mentioned TIBCO API and that in turn updates the spreadsheet (using my Google credentials) with response submitted by user

With this arrangement, I don't have to share my Google spreadsheet with all users and expose all submissions. I could have used Google Form, but that is too basic and my UI requirements are quite complex.

Until this point, everything works fine, ***but*** as a part of some advance features, I want some functions (written in the script of backend spreadsheet) to trigger on 'onEdit' when my API call write to the spreadsheet and that is where I am stuck. So far, I have tried:

- Exposing Google [Script as an REST](https://trevorfox.com/2015/03/rest-api-with-google-apps-script/) API
- Exposing Google Script as Library function

but in all cases, I have to share the spreadsheet with user that invokes the calls, and I dont want that, thanks.

Comment: Cannot be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from `I want some functions (written in the script of backend spreadsheet) to trigger on 'onEdit' when my API call write to the spreadsheet`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, when `my API` puts the value using Sheets API, is OnChange trigger useful for your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike - The API write call is not really flexible, all I can do is dump some values in the spreadsheet. So my plan is to have a trigger on 'onEdit(e)' and get the range just updated by 'e', make some changes to submission e.g. changing dumped values status from 'pending' to 'in progress, send an email to the recipient etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: So what is stopping you from making this ```onEdit``` updates when you call the API? I.e your apps script code makes a call to an API, receives a response and updates the Spreadsheet, why dont you on the same function after updating those ranges run what you needed to run with an onEdit? Theoretically you would already know which ranges have been modified in that function as you just set the up.

Comment: Users access independent Script 'A' with HTML UI > On submission, REST service invoked from HTML > REST service dumps user inputs as rows to backend spreadsheet which has another native script e.g. 'B'. I want trigger in 'B' to execute 'onEdit(e)' when the data is dumped.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what `onEdit` is doing? Please provide the code related to the UI, the REST service and the `onEdit` actions.